# POSIX thread and related community or poeple of behind it

Tags: unix, pthreads, kernel, shared-libraries

It's a conceptual question, not coding!

I used `POSIX thread` in 2 project.But i don't know which community behind of this big and useful library.

I googled but didn't result.So it's very intereseting to how it grow up? Which community support it? `kernel`? or is supported by `FSF (FreeSoftware Fundation)` or companies?

Please name by reference.....!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POSIX is an open standard.  It is a registered trade mark of the IEEE and in their purview.

http://www.ieee.org/
and
http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1003.0-1995.html

UNIX is trademarked and controlled by the Open Group.

http://www.opengroup.org/

Comment: The origins of POSIX arguably date back to DOD standards applied to early Unix distributions.

Comment: Specific implementation methods by operating system differ.  In the case of Linux, GNU ( www.gnu.org ) and the Linux kernel ( www.kernel.org ) are responsible for providing the necessary code to adhere to POSIX.

Comment: i was searshing , but didn't find any active mailing list  about pthread.You mean kernel team develop pthread lib?

Comment: If you are using Linux, you are probably directly referring to GLib.  

http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/

GLIB is a specific implementation of a part of what the Posix standard defines threads to be.  They are basically implementing the standard for GNU / Linux.  The Linux Kernel Supports that as well.  So the IEEE, the Linux kernel team ( LKML ), and GNU together create what you use in linux.  

The link referenced has the GNU mailing list listed.